# Average value of the pivots found during LU factorization.

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Following is an exercise from 'Linear algebra and its applications' by Gilbert Strang.

> Find experimentally the average size (absolute value) of the first and second and
>   third pivots for MATLAB's lu(rand(3, 3)). The average of the first pivot from

I wrote the following octave code for this exercise:

```
s1 = 0;
s2 = 0;
s3 = 0;
n = 1000;
for i=1:n
    [L, U] = lu(rand(3,3));
    s1 += abs(U(1,1));
    s2 += abs(U(2,2));
    s3 += abs(U(3,3));
end

disp(s1/n)
disp(s2/n)
disp(s3/n)
```

The exercise states that the average value of the first pivot shoult be `0.5`, but the above code produces this output:

```
> octave t.m
 0.74990
 0.49116
 0.36700
```

Why do these results disagree with what's stated in the exercise? Is their a proof for the result stated in the exercise?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's one of the questions I asked.

Comment: @YvesDaoust `Is their a proof for the result stated in the exercise?`

Answer (score 0):

With total pivoting, the first pivot is the element with the largest absolute value. In a set of nine uniformly distributed random numbers in $[0,1]$, the expectation is $\dfrac9{9+1}$.

Using partial pivoting only the first column is involved, and $\dfrac3{3+1}$.

---

$\dfrac12$ is the expectation of every single element.

Comment: $0.5$ is indeed the average of each single element in `rand(3,3)`, but why does the text calls it "the average of the first pivot from `abs(A(1,1))`"?